# force-window-update vs redisplay

Tags: header-line, idle-timer, redisplay

During idle time with `run-with-idle-timer` I parse text around a point and update `header-line-format`.

Unfortunately I can't see update to header line unless I type any key. So I should trigger redisplay.

With `(redisplay)` header line isn't updated. With `(force-window-update)` it is updated.

I am not sure what function is appropriated for my usage scenario. There are also `redraw-frame` and `redraw-display` and possibly many others.

What function is more efficient in performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(force-mode-line-update)`  or all with the optional `t`:  "*Force redisplay of the current buffer’s mode line and header line.  With optional non-nil ALL, force redisplay of all mode lines and header lines.  This function also forces recomputation of the menu bar menus and the frame title.*"  Here is a link to the manual entry:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Basics.html